# Unable to console.log value using http post subscribe method

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I simply want to read the array values inside console using `console.log`.

I am able to see the response in my browser, even `console.log(data) shows me this result in the browser -

[image]

[image]

my `communication.ts` code is -

```
import { Component , OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { commservice } from './commservice';
import {listenToElementOutputs} from "@angular/core/src/view/element";
import { Http,Response,Headers } from '@angular/http';

/**
 * Generated class for the CommunicationPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-communication',
  templateUrl: 'communication.html',
  providers: [commservice]
})
export class CommunicationPage implements OnInit {
public SNO;dataa;TASK;TAG_DT;TAG_FROM;TAG_TO;TAG;STATUS;ENTRYFROM;ISREAD;
  private _url:string = "http://219.90.67.154/quicktask/webservice /taskcom.php?taskno=";
  constructor(private _http : Http,public _commservice: commservice, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }



  ngOnInit()
  {

              this.SNO=this.navParams.get("sno");
              console.log(this.SNO);

    let params;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   // return this._http.post(this._url+this.SNO,params,{headers:headers})
     // .map((response:Response) => response.json());


      return this._http.post(this._url+this.SNO,params,{headers:headers})
      .subscribe(data =>  {console.log(data);});



  }

}
```

If i use postman by passing the url, i am getting the desired result, if everything is fine then why am i not getting the result for `.subscribe(data =>  {console.log(data[0]);});`  or `.subscribe(data =>  {console.log(data[0].TAG);});`

> Please help

Attaching postman image for reference if needed
[image]

Comment: Try to add `map` like this `return this._http.post(this._url+this.SNO,params,{headers:headers}).map((res: Response) => res.json() || {}).subscribe(data => {console.log(JSON.stringify(data));});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because what you are console loggin first is the whole `Response`, so what you want to console log inside the subscribe is the `JSON`:

```
.subscribe(data =>  {console.log(data.json()[0])
```

notice `json()`

Comment: it worked but can you guide me why my others services are working without `data.json()`  ?  I mean my login service i just need to type 'data[0].result` to get the value from `"Result" : "1" , but why i need to do differently on this one ?  php side code may be needs some alterations  ?

Comment: I don't know how your other data looks like, but this is JSON, so it needs to be treated accordingly. Also I am suspicious of how `data[0].result` would work for example if you were to get string text, you'd still need to parse it to JSON before using it. But as said, I don't know your code :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using Json.stringify
like this

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

This could have different reasons:

You have a space in your `_url` variable after `/webservice`:

```
private _url:string = "http://219.90.67.154/quicktask/webservice /taskcom.php?taskno=";
```

But when I see it right you have the space in your postman request so I don't think that this is the reason.

What about `params` and `this.SNO`? Are they defined at the time of your request?

**Update**

To create an object from the response you can use `JSON.parse(data._body)`. To get `TAG` for example you need to use `JSON.parse(data._body)[0].TAG`.

Comment: i have removed the space, its not the issue, params are unused because i have passed the no. here `this._url+this.SNO` , result is coming right but why like this - `Response {_body: ` and why not just the result so i can use data[0].TAG

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.log(data._body);` Then you will receive stringed json object that you sent from the post man. You can use `JSON.parse(data._body)` to get object from the json string.